# Alsa capture microphone has reversed auto gain control on Logitech G430

Tags: alsa, microphone

I don't know how to describe this problem but basically I have a USB microphone, from a Logitech G430 headset, that has a reversed auto gain control, so when I speak louder the volume increases, and when I talk normal or whisper it's really low, this happens only with the capture control in alsamixer, when I hear it in the mic playback it sounds fantastic.
I have no modules for gain control in pulse, and there is only one control for the Capture section in alsamixer.

---

[image: alsamixer]

---

[Here is a test to check how it sounds](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5SnZpbZHB_c) recorded with audacity.

---

I don't really know what's the problem, this is the output for **amixer**:

```
Simple mixer control 'Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 65536
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 38011 [58%] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 38011 [58%] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Capture',0
  Capabilities: cvolume cvolume-joined cswitch cswitch-joined
  Capture channels: Mono
  Limits: Capture 0 - 65536
  Mono: Capture 65536 [100%] [on]
```

and for **arecord --list-devices**:

```
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC887-VD Analog [ALC887-VD Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 2: ALC887-VD Alt Analog [ALC887-VD Alt Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 3: Headset [Logitech G430 Gaming Headset], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

How do I disable this or, in the worst case, how do I change the playback Mic to work as Capture?